# DoesNotExist at /admin/login/ after upgrading to Django 1.8

Tags: python, django

After upgrade from django 1.7 to 1.8, I can't able to access my admin portal. I get the following error:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/login/
Site matching query does not exist.
```

As mentioned in other questions, I have change my `TEMPLATES` setting, but it does not help.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'MyANSRSource/templates/MyANSRSource/'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'employee/template/'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'employee/emp_photo/'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                #global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
                #    'django.template.context_processors.request',

                #),
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: You haven't said what happens, or why you think the templates directory is to blame. What error do you get?

Comment: I checked other similar question where solution was to add template tag

Comment: but that is also not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? **What error do you get**?

Comment: Site matching query does not exist

Comment: when i am trying to access admin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have `SITE_ID` in your settings, [Django 1.8, will try to use the hostname](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#django-contrib-sites) (e.g. `127.0.0.1:8000`) to find the site.  If you don't have a site with that domain name in your database, then you will get the error:

```
Site matching query does not exist.
```

You have a few options:

1. You might not require the sites framework. You could try removing it from `'django.contrib.sites'` from your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.
2. In your settings, set `SITE_ID` to the value of the site you want to use. `SITE_ID = 1` will probably work, if you haven't made any changes to the sites in the database.
3. Change the domain of the site in the database (e.g. from `example.com` to `127.0.0.1:8000`). This is the most fragile fix, because your project will now work for `127.0.0.1:8000`, but not for `localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a new user by running the command `manage.py createsuperuser`. Log in with this user, you should be able to access the admin panel now.

Then find your user object and make sure it has the correct permissions. as stated in the 1.8 changelog under [Minor features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#minor-features).

When I upgraded I lacked the correct permission to access the admin panel.